# Making foreach go through all values of a variable + return the current value

Tags: loops, foreach, stata

I want to build an iteration using the Stata FAQ [here](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/try-all-values-with-foreach/). The second method seems fitting for my case. I have built the following code:

```
levelsof ID, local(levels)
foreach l of local levels {
    var var1 var2 if ID == `l', lags(1/4) vsquish
    vargranger
}
```

Idea: iterate over all IDs in `ID`, then do `vargranger`. However, it runs once, then outputs `no observations`. Which is not true, as I have 200 IDs in my search variable.

Second thing I want to add into my loop, a `return / print` function of the current ID used in `ID`.

The output should look like this, for each value of `ID`:

```
ID = XYZ

Sample:  2001 - 2019                            Number of obs     =         16
...

vargranger

   Granger causality Wald tests
  +------------------------------------------------------------------+
  |          Equation           Excluded |   chi2     df Prob > chi2 |
  |--------------------------------------+---------------------------|
  |         var1                    var2 |  11.617     4    0.020    |
  |         var1                     ALL |  11.617     4    0.020    |
  |--------------------------------------+---------------------------|
  |         var2                    var1 |  6.2796     4    0.179    |
  |         var2                     ALL |  6.2796     4    0.179    |
  +------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display` of the current level is easy enough, say:

```
levelsof ID, local(levels)
foreach l of local levels {
    di "{title:`l'}" _n 
    count if !missing(var1, var2) & ID == `l'
    var var1 var2 if ID == `l', lags(1/4) vsquish
    vargranger
}
```

The report "no observations" is presumably coming from `var` and is not a reflection of how many identifiers you have. You should add checks like that above for (e.g.) how many observations you have to play with.

Comment: Thanks Nick! Actually waited for your reply and it worked **exactly** how I intended it to look like. And yes, you're right, I forgot that ```var``` may stop on no observations.